# How can I define object type which is same as level 1 but differ rest levels in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 objects, they same props but differ the result of that props.

```
const tom = {
    getAction: () => ({
        eat: () => {},
        sleep: () => {},
    }),
}

const steve = {
    getAction: () => ({
        work: () => {}
    }),
}
```

My func would like to combine 2 object and extra getAction function to parent

```
const mapObjIndexed = <K extends string, T, R>(fn: (value: T) => R, data: Record<K,T>) => {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((previous, key) => ({
        ...previous,
        [key]: fn(data[key])
    }),{})
}
interface Person<T> {
    getAction: () => T
}
const combineAction = <G, K extends string, T extends Person<G>>(people: Record<K, T>) => {
    return mapObjIndexed((item) => item.getAction(), people)
}
const actions = combineAction({tom, steve})

// So I can do like this
actions.tom.eat() // problems at tom
actions.tom.sleep() // same

actions.steve.work() // same
```

There are 2 problems here:

1st: How can I define the return type of mapObjectIndexed

2nd: How typescript know tom props contains eat and sleep func and steve has work

Thank to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural return type for `mapObjIndexed` based on the parameter types you have specified would be `Record<K, R>`.  (You'll have to cast the returned expression to `Record<K, R>` because TypeScript isn't smart enough to see that you are adding all the required properties one by one.)

However, this isn't useful for the `combineAction` use case because every person in the input to `combineAction` has a *different* type `T` and you want the corresponding property of the output to have the corresponding type `R`.  You can express the type of `combineAction` as follows using mapped types:

```
const combineAction = <P extends { [N in keyof P]: Person<{}> }>(people: P):
    { [N in keyof P]: ReturnType<P[N]["getAction"]> } => {
    return <any>mapObjIndexed((item) => item.getAction(), people)
}
```

However, there's no good way to declare a type for `mapObjIndexed` that will allow you to implement `combineAction` via a call to `mapObjIndexed` without a cast, since you would essentially have to parameterize `mapObjIndexed` over the *relationship* between an original property type `P[N]` and the transformed property type `ReturnType<P[N]["getAction"]>`.  To do that, `mapObjIndexed` would have to have a [higher-kinded type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which currently isn't supported by TypeScript, though some limited workarounds exist.  If I were in your situation, I would probably declare the type of `combineAction` and not worry about the cast in the implementation.